# Delphi and attachment files in MS access database

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I search many times in Google, SO, and I can't find anything about working with attachment via delphi, so I decide to write this question.

I have a table in `.accdb` database called *Files* with those fields:

```
IDFile PK AutoIncField,
FileName WideStringField,
FilesAttached WideMemoFiled.
```

[image]

How can I save/load files to/from attachment fields using delphi?

**[Attach files and graphics to the records in your database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd#bm1)**

The problem here, in delphi the datatype of `FilesAttached` is `TWideMemoField`,
when I write `ShowMessage(FDTable1FilesAttached.Value);` it give just the name of the attachment.

I don't know how to Insert/save files to/from that field using delphi.

Comment: @DownVoter As I say before, don't just dv and leave, tell us what's wrong with the question, what's your point of view, even the visiters can find this comments helpful and make theire Qs beter.

Comment: @MartynA You mean `TBlobField(FDTable1FilesAttached)`?

Comment: Attachment data type is a structure, not just a file stream (it can hold multiple files btw.). There is no official description of this structure and will be subject to change, so I would just avoid using this type. P.S. do not attempt to typecast field accessor the proposed way.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't seem that hard to find VBA/C# examples of working with .accdb Attachment fields which should translate fairly easily into Delphi.  However, it turned out to be more difficult than I imagined to find something that a) hadn't misunderstood what Attachment fields actually are and b) actually works.  Skip to the **update** section below.

For example, googling

> accdb create attachment in vba

gives numerous hits including this one

http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/working-with-attachment-fields.html

which you might try as a starting point. It uses MS DAO objects, and includes straightforward code for storing files to Attachment fields and for accessing them.  You would need to create a Delphi wrapper unit for the DAO type library, if you don't already have one, using the IDE's `Import Type Library`

If you would prefer something ADO-based, you might take a look at

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/843001/Handling-fields-of-Attachment-type-in-MS-Access-us

**Update**  See the function `OpenFirstAttachmentAsTempFile` in the post by "aspen" (date = 4/11/2012 07:18 am) in this thread

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=224112&page=2

which shows an apparently successful attempt to extract a file from an `attachment` field (the thread also contains several other attempts at coding this function).

Note in particular this line

```
Set rstChild = rstCurrent.Fields(strFieldName).Value ' the .Value for a complex field returns the underlying recordset
```

which implies that the `Value` of the attachment field can return a recordset which contains the attached file(s).

Presumably, importing a recent version of the DAO type library into Delphi would allow
a Delphi app to do the same thing, and then one could reverse-engineer the `rstChild` recordset to see how to populate this field in code.  I haven't done that yet, though.

Comment: You are right. Actually, without reverse engineering of the `Attachment` data type structure you won't be able to insert a row into such table. You can read the attachment file data by accessing that column fields, like for example `SELECT FilesAttached.FileData FROM Files` and you'll receive a blob field with the file data (the tuple will be splitted into multiple when having multiple files attached in that field). How to insert data into such table with an ODBC client library is a mystery.

Comment: @Victoria:  Yes, well.  I was amused by the comment in the ADO article `// Do something with data ...`   - makes it sound so easy ;=)

Comment: Well, it will be blob internally, I bet. But structured, and so long we have no definition of that structure we can only guess. I've tried with no success.

Comment: @Victoria:  I was wondering if internally it was some kind of OLE storage, as MS have had all the engineering for for that stuff for years but frankly I can't summon the enthusiasm to spend much time finding out.

Comment: I believe that OLE object would have been fetched as `SQL_LONGVARBINARY` (see [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types)). But hard to guess for me as well. Inserting into such field is impossible without knowing that structure. Fetching is.